# Why can't I parse this string to DateTimeOffset with my system clock set to Hong Kong time?

Tags: c#, datetimeoffset

If you change your system clock

**FROM:** for example Hong Kong time or China Standard Time (UTC +8)

**TO:** EST Eastern Standard time (UTC -5)

Then below code will work.

DateTimeOffset don’t like "0001-01-01T00:00:00" if clock isn't set to EST?

```
string token = "0001-01-01T00:00:00";
if (!DateTimeOffset.TryParse(token, out var offsetDate))
{
   Console.WriteLine(“Why?”);
}
```

Why...?

Answer (score 3):

If your're on EST time then that value represents a UTC time greater than 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM +00:00, which is the minimum value for `DateTimeOffset`. So you're okay.

If you're on Hong Kong time, the value would be less than `DateTimeOffset.MinValue`. The value can't be represented as a `DateTimeOffset`, so the `TryParse` fails.

Comment: This is correct.  But also note that if the input time is *intended* to be in UTC then you can avoid this by either including a trailing `Z` in the input string, or by passing `DateTimeStyle.AssumeUniversal` to the `TryParse` method.